# i have to access desktop remotely using iphone/ipad?

Tags: iphone

I have accessed desktop remotely using iphone/ipad with bluetooth. but i can't see the desktop screen.

Thanks
Pankaj Chauhan

Comment: Thanks for the update. Did you have a question too?

Answer (score 0):

logmein has a decent app for that.

https://secure.logmein.com/US/welcome/iphone/?wt.ac=1-1

Comment: But I have to develop an app as developed by logmein. Please let me know iphone sdk api or code for that......